# Closed form for infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^n \left[1-(\tfrac{j}{n}u+v)^2\right]^{-1} x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, generating-functions, closed-form, gamma-function

I've been struggling to find a closed form for the following series that depends on $u$ and $v$ as parameters:

$$
f(u,v,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^n
$$

with

$$
c_n = \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n \left[1-(\tfrac{j}{n}u+v)^2\right]} .
$$

Any ideas or insight will be appreciated!

---

Here are some things I've tried. First, for the special case $u=0$, the series is a geometric series and the result is

$$
f(x,0,v) = \frac{x}{1-x-v^2}.
$$

In general, it's possible to factor the denominator in $c_n$ as follows

$$
c_n = \frac{1}{\left(\prod_{j=1}^n \left[1+v+\tfrac{j}{n}u\right]\right)
\left(\prod_{j=1}^n \left[1-v-\tfrac{j}{n}u\right]\right)} .
$$

Not really sure if this factorization is useful, but Mathematica does something similar and immediately puts $c_n$ in the form

$$
c_n = \frac{(-1)^n \left(\tfrac{n}{u}\right)^{(2n)}}{\left(1+\tfrac{(v+1)n}{u}\right)_n \left(1+\tfrac{(v-1)n}{u}\right)_n}
$$
where $(\cdot)_n$ is a [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) (rising factorial). This form has some appealing symmetry, but Mathematica is unable to complete the sum.

---

Finally, here are some potentially-related problems:

- [Trying to prove that $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^j \frac{2 k}{j+k-1} = \pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420732/trying-to-prove-that-sum-j-2-infty-prod-k-1j-frac2-kjk-1-pi)
- [On the closed form for $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{4n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009343/on-the-closed-form-for-sum-m-0-infty-prod-n-1m-fracn4n-1)
- [Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{m}(n+k)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477174/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1-prod-limits-k-1mnk)
- [Closed form of series with factorial-squared denominator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466836/closed-form-of-series-with-factorial-squared-denominator?)
- [Infinite series with a rising factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088930/infinite-series-with-a-rising-factorial)